# Divide the contents of cells in Excel across other cells at a specific character?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I currently have the following data that I need to split up into two individual cells.

```
| (GMT+01:00) Brussels, Copenhagen, Madrid, Paris     |
| (GMT-08:00) Pacific Time (US & Canada); Tijuana     |
| (GMT) Dublin, Edinburgh, Lisbon, London             |
| (GMT) Greenwich Mean Time                           |
```

For example, I need the above to become the following:

```
| GMT+01:00   |   Brussels, Copenhagen, Madrid, Paris   |
| GMT-08:00   |   Pacific Time (US & Canada); Tijuana   |
| GMT         |   Dublin, Edinburgh, Lisbon, London     |
| GMT         |   Greenwich Mean Time                   |
```

I have attempted to use the 'Text to Columns' tool, although I had no luck since some data entries contain more than one open and close bracket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided you can always count on `)` (right parenthesis and space) being a delimiter in your data, you can use find and replace to change those two characters to an unused character such as `~`. Then use Text to Columns with `~` as the delimiter.

If that option is unavailable, you can use the `LEFT`, `RIGHT`, and `FIND` functions to extract the right information.